# How to implement NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, navigation-drawer

I am developing the android application. 
Firstly, I use the drop-down menu with intent function to link all of my activity in my application so in my application all of file are extended from "Activity" but now
I want to use "navigation drawer" in my project instead of drop-down menu.
As I knew, Navigation Drawer is only applied to the Fragment,isn't it?

I want to know that How can I use navigation drawer in my project? 
Thank you for all answer and Sorry with my English.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this awesome tutorial of how to use a **NavigationDrawer** in your project:

> http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

This comes from Google itself and explains the usage and implementation of the NavigationDrawer in detail.

And yes, it would be best practice to use **Fragments** for the individual sections of the Drawer.